# Remove attribute from XML node?

Tags: .net, json, node.js, xml, xml2js

I have some  XML which I have to convert to JSON. The XML has nodes like

```
<Title xml:lang="en">The Steal In The Wheels</Title>
```

I want to remove this `xml:lang="en"` from the xml nodes.

Actually, I am working in node.js and I need title value. I am converting XML to JSON using xml2js. It is converting to JSON but it is giving title value with style. So that I am trying to remove this attribute.

Comment: Well, have you tried anything yet? What format do you have the XML in at the moment - just as a string, or as an `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`? If you can easily get at it as an `XDocument`, then removing the attribute will be trivial...

Comment: I have an xml document.

Comment: Do you mean `XmlDocument`? It's really unclear at the moment. It would be much better if you'd provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was converting xml to json and when i was trying to get the value of title then it was coming with style.

So that i asked this question. Now i got the solution so that i want to share with you if anybody from you stucked like me then it will help you.

Here is the code:

var xml2js = require('xml2js');

function GetRequestBody(data){

```
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser({ignoreAttrs : true, mergeAttrs : false});
    parser.parseString(data.toString(), function (err, result) {
    var post_data = querystring.stringify({
                      'name' : result.Documents.Content[0].Title 
                  });

     return post_data;
    });
}
```